# Finding vertex arrays for common objects

Tags: graphics, 3d

Where can I find 3d vertex data of some common objects? Consider the [teapot](https://www.sjbaker.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_History_of_The_Teapot) for example. If possible, model with vertex colors are favoured.

This question does not strictly belong here. If necessary, move it.

Comment: If you mean the commonly used *Stanford models* - Suzanne (chimp), Lucy (angel), Buddha, Dragon, Bunny, and others - http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/. The (Utah) teapot itself is elsewhere though

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for your input. I browsed through some of these models and observed that all of them have 100s of thousands of vertices. I am using openGL for rendering, and I need to perform operations like rotating and translating. Where can I get something with lesser vertices, that can be easily rendered on an ordinary PC?

Comment: If you google the individual models by their name, e.g. "Stanford bunny", there should be various free websites that come up, e.g. turbosquid, tf3dm